# showimagepreview não funciona no safari

Tags: jquery, ajax

Tenho esse script para dar um preview da imagem antes do upload funciona perfeitamente no ie chrome e firefox menos no safari... alguém já teve problemas com safari?? se alguém puder dar um dica... agraço

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function showimagepreview(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var filerdr = new FileReader();
        filerdr.onload = function(e) {
            $('#foto').attr('src', e.target.result);
            $("#ft").fadeOut();
            $("#foto").fadeIn(1000);
            $("#label").fadeIn(1000);
        }
        filerdr.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="" method="Post" enctype="multipart/form-data"  name="form" id="form">
        <label id="label" style="display:none;">
        <div id="dft1" class="img_preview">
            <div class="img_prev">
                <img id="foto" style="display:none;"/>
            </div>
        </div></label>
        <input type="file" class="input_file" name="ft" id="ft" onchange="showimagepreview(this)"/>
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: O que lhe aparece na consola se fizer `console.log(typeof FileReader);`? Acho que o Safari tem problemas com o FileReader...

Comment: @Sergio É curioso que na página do plugin indicado pelo Tony tem *This plugin is **unmaintained** and **unsupported** as File API is now widely supported (almost 80% global support – http://caniuse.com/fileapi)*... E o caniuse indica que Safari é ok (?)...

Comment: @brasofilo daí a minha pergunta sobre o que dá o console.log. Eu acho que só as versões inferiores à 6 têm este problema e o Safari é bom a forçar auto-updates.

Comment: eu resolvi usando a funçao if(window.FileReader)

Answer (score 0):

Tente usar esta biblioteca, que resolve a falta do suporte ao **FileReader** no **Safari**:

https://github.com/Jahdrien/FileReader